# Compare values from a range (e.g. column D) with values in a range beside (e.g. column C)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare values from a range (e.g. column D) with values in a range beside (e.g. column C), which highlights the columns that has a different value in red, after which it moves right to compare the next range of values beside (i.e. Column E) with Column D and so on until there is a blank range of columns.

These are my codes. Application defined error.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(, 1))
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formulal:=ActiveCell.Select <> ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0

    End With
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't look as if it was copied directly from the VBA editor. Could you please edit your question and paste the actual code?

Comment: @FunThomas apologies, first time user here. Does the code look alright now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - you need to construct a formula for the CF rule, using the Address() property of the first cell in the two ranges being compared.  When you apply the rule the formula will adjust for each row, so no need to go cell-by-cell.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rngCF As Range, addr1, addr2, cf As FormatCondition
    
    Set rngCF = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
    addr1 = rngCF.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
    addr2 = rngCF.Offset(0, -1).Cells(1).Address(False, False) 'one column to left
    
    Set cf = rngCF.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                        Formula1:="=" & addr1 & "<>" & addr2)
    With cf
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: wow you’re great! It works thanks!! Could you share with me what does addr1 and addr2 do and how does that affect the conditional formatting formula?

Comment: addr1 and 2 are just the cell addresses for the two cells being compared.  So if `rngCf` is B2:B10 the formula used for the CF rule is `=B2<>A2` .  When calling `Address()` use the arguments shown or you get the absolute address: if you used (eg)  `=$B$2<>$A$2` as the CF formula it wouldn't auto-adjust for the other cells in the range.